# How to set cookie to value of checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to make a function that sets a cookie to a true/false value depending on if a checkbox has been clicked or not. I can then use this value when the page loads to render the checkbox as toggled.

HTML:

```html
<form name="example">
  <div class="checklist-item">
    <label for="example">Example</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="example" name="example">
  </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```js
document.getElementById("example").addEventListener("click", exampleCookie)
function exampleCookie() {
    document.cookie = "exampleCookie";
}
```

How might I use the function `exampleCookie` to be equal to the value of the checkbox?

Comment: use 'change' instead of 'click'

Comment: @EbrahimKhalilAmid I was initially using 'change' I am more looking for solutions regarding setting the value of a cookie to that of a form selection value.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i give you a referrence from here https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-cookies
maybe it helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
</head>  
<body>  
        <select id="color" onchange="display()">  
                <option value="Select Color">Select Color</option>  
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>  
                <option value="green">Green</option>  
                <option value="red">Red</option>  
            </select>  
            <script type="text/javascript">  
                function display()  
                {  
                    var value = document.getElementById("color").value;  
                    if (value != "Select Color")  
                    {  
                        document.bgColor = value;  
                        document.cookie = "color=" + value;  
                    }  
                }  
                window.onload = function ()  
                {  
                    if (document.cookie.length != 0)  
                    {  
                        var array = document.cookie.split("=");  
                        document.getElementById("color").value = array[1];  
                        document.bgColor = array[1];  
                    }  
                }  
              
                  
            </script>  
</body>  
</html>
```